# T4 Scaffolding - How to detect Nullable Types

Tags: powershell, t4scaffolding

I am trying to generate a Class by loading another Class as model, here is the **class\model i am using**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace Sma.Domain.Model {

    public class Smartistdetails {
        public Smartistdetails() { }
        [Key]
        public int ArtistID { get; set; }
        public string BandName? { get; set; }
        public string LoginName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }     
    }
}
```

as you see that there are some nullable types like `public string BandName? { get; set; }` this is where i have the problem. I ma successfully making the output class but when a property of the model is nullable i want to detect it and act accordingly, I don't know how to do that.

Here is my t4 template

```
<#@ Template Language="C#" HostSpecific="True" Inherits="DynamicTransform" #>
<#@ Output Extension="cs" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Entity" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Linq.Mapping" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>

using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using Sma.Domain.Model; 
<#
   var modelType = (CodeType)Model.ModelType; 
   var modelName = modelType.Name; 
   var properties = modelType.VisibleMembers().OfType<CodeProperty>();      
   var primaryKeyProperty = modelType.VisibleMembers().OfType<CodeProperty>().Single(x => x.Name == Model.PrimaryKey);
#>

namespace <#= Model.Namespace #>.Mapping
{
    public class <#= Model.EntityName #>Map : ClassMap<<#= Model.EntityName #>> 
    {       
        public <#= Model.EntityName #>Map() {
        Table("<#= Model.EntityName #>");
        LazyLoad();     
<# var type = "";
var typeName = "";
foreach (var property in properties) 
{
type = GetType(property.Type); 
typeName = GetTypeName(property.Type);
if( isType(type) )
{
if( Model.PrimaryKey == property.Name )
{
#>
        Id(x => x.<#= property.Name #>).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("<#= property.Name #>");
<#      
}
else
{
#>
        Map(x=>x.<#= property.Name #>).Column("<#= property.Name #>");      
<#}
}
else
{
#>
        References(x=>x.<#= property.Name #>);              
<#
}
}
#>      }
    }
}

<#+
    string GetType(EnvDTE.CodeTypeRef type)
    {                                                                                                                                             
        string str = "";
        if (type.UnderlyingTypeIs<byte>())
            str = "byte";
        else if (type.UnderlyingTypeIs<sbyte>())
            str = "sbyte";
        else if (type.UnderlyingTypeIs<int>())
            str = "int";
        else if (type.UnderlyingTypeIs<uint>())
            str = "uint";
        else if (type.UnderlyingTypeIs<short>())
            str = "short";
        else if (type.UnderlyingTypeIs<ushort>())
            str = "ushort";
        else if (type.UnderlyingTypeIs<DateTime>())
            str = "DateTime";
        else if (type.UnderlyingTypeIs<long>())
            str = "long";
        else if (type.UnderlyingTypeIs<ulong>())
            str = "ulong";
        else if (type.UnderlyingTypeIs<double>())
            str = "double";
        else if (type.UnderlyingTypeIs<bool>())
            str = "bool";
        else if (type.UnderlyingTypeIs<string>())
            str = "string";
        else if (type.UnderlyingTypeIs<decimal>())
            str = "decimal";
        else
            str = type.AsFullName.ToString();

        return str;
    }

    string GetTypeName(EnvDTE.CodeTypeRef type)
    {  
        string str = type.AsFullName.ToString();
        return str;
    }

    bool isType(string _type)
    {
        if( _type == "byte" ) return true;
        else if( _type == "sbyte" ) return true;
        else if( _type == "int" ) return true;
        else if( _type == "uint" ) return true;
        else if( _type == "short" ) return true;
        else if( _type == "ushort" ) return true;
        else if( _type == "DateTime" ) return true;
        else if( _type == "long" ) return true;
        else if( _type == "ulong" ) return true;
        else if( _type == "double" ) return true;
        else if( _type == "bool" ) return true;
        else if( _type == "string" ) return true;
        else if( _type == "decimal" ) return true;
        return false;
    }
#>
```

before `Map(x=>x.<#= property.Name #>).Column("<#= property.Name #>");` i want to check if the property is nullable if not i want to specify `Map(x=>x.<#= property.Name #>).Column("<#= property.Name #>").NotNullable();`

**How to do it**

just in-case here is my .ps1 powershell script

```
[T4Scaffolding.Scaffolder(Description = "Enter a description of ExtMapping here")][CmdletBinding()]
param(        
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)][string]$ModelType,
    [string]$Project,
    [string]$CodeLanguage,
    [string[]]$TemplateFolders,
    [switch]$Force = $false 
)

$mynamespace = "Sma"
$projectFor = $mynamespace + ".Infrastructure.Data"
$namespace = $projectFor # (Get-Project $projectFor).Properties.Item("DefaultNamespace").Value
$outputPath =  "Mapping\" + $ModelType
Write-Host "Scaffolding $ModelType ExtMapping..."

$useModelFromProject = $mynamespace + ".Domain"
# get the modelType object from the name
$foundModelType = Get-ProjectType $ModelType -Project $useModelFromProject -BlockUi
$primaryKey = Get-PrimaryKey $ModelType -Project $useModelFromProject
$modelOutputPath = "Mapping\" + $ModelType + "Map"

Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate $modelOutputPath -Template ExtMapping `
    -Model @{ 
    Namespace = $namespace; 
    ModelType = [MarshalByRefObject]$foundModelType; 
    PrimaryKey = $primaryKey;
    EntityName = $ModelType } `
    -SuccessMessage "Added ExtMapping output at $projectFor" `
    -TemplateFolders $TemplateFolders -Project $projectFor -CodeLanguage $CodeLanguage -Force:$Force
```

Comment: Did anyone get this working? The proposed answer only works for the "old" nullable value types (Nullable<int>), but not for the new C# nullable object annotations (string?, object?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Get-ProjectType $ModelType).Children | Where-Object{ $_.Type.CodeType.Name -eq "Nullable"} | ForEach{"$($_.Name),$($_.Type.AsString)"}
```

This snippet will extract nullables and display them as "PropetyName, NullableType" from the class name contained in $ModelType

Comment: This might work for nullable value types like ´Nullable<int>´. There the type is the generic type "Nullable" with type parameter. But it does NOT work for the OP question, where you have a ´string?´ property. CodeType.Name gives you "String", not "Nullable". There are also no attibutes or parameters on the property. Has anyone succeeded to get the nullable object flag for C# nullability?